# iPhone sandbox environment asks for credit card

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I previously successfully created an app including in-app and was able to test then in sandbox environment before submitting to app store.
Now I am working on update.  I am not able to test in-app in sandbox.  I have my iphone logged out of app store.  When I click on purchase, it takes me to credit card info.
I eliminated the test user and creates a new test user but the same thing is happening.

Please help

Answer (score 4):

I figured the issue.  We need to delete the previous installation of app from device before we do this test.